# ASP.NET MVC file uploading with different inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I search so much for my problem, it seems so easy but did not get correct answer.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<input type="file" name="smallImage" id="smallImage" /> 
<input type="file" name="largeImage" id="largeImage" />
```

I can get files with `Request.Files`, but it does not give me the `HTML file input` info which the file is coming from.

As you see, I must understand which file input element sends the file.

Edit:
I try this but did not work also

```
Request.Files["smallImage"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use 2 arguments of type `HttpPostedFileBase` in your HttpPost action method with same name as of your input field(s).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase smallImage,
                                                     HttpPostedFileBase largeImage)
{
  // check smallImage & largeImage here
  // to do  : Return something
}
```

Assuming your form action value is set to this action method

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourControllerName", FormMethod.Post,
                                          new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   <input type="file" name="smallImage" /> 
   <input type="file" name="largeImage" /> 
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: OMG I forgot to add enctype attribute to my form. You make me see this thanks a lot. After that, `Request.Files["largeImage"]` also worked. But your solution much better.